# String.valueOf(Integer) always return 1

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm trying to parse String "2 2 2" and add every symbol '2' in ArrayList.
This is my code:

```
charCounter = 0;
rawSize = 0;
while(charCounter < line.length()){
    a_char = line.charAt(charCounter);
       if(a_char != ' '){
           System.out.print(String.valueOf(a_char)+" ");
           temp = Character.digit(a_char, 10);
           myIntArray.add(temp);
           System.out.println(String.valueOf(myIntArray.get(rawSize)));
           rawSize++;
    }
    charCounter++;
}
```

I can't understand why `System.out.println(String.valueOf(myIntArray.get(rawSize)));`always return 1 ?

UPDDATE:

I try read file, which contain next text:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Here is my Main function:

public static void main(String[] args){

```
char a_char = ' ';
int charCounter = 0;
int temp = 0;
String line = null; 
String file = "C:\\Users\\KUser\\Desktop\\SImpleIteration\\matrix.txt";
BufferedReader reader = null;

ArrayList myIntArray = new ArrayList();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            charCounter = 0;
            rawSize = 0;
            while(charCounter < line.length()){
                a_char = line.charAt(charCounter);
                if(a_char != ' '){
                    System.out.print(String.valueOf(a_char)+" ");
                    temp = Character.digit(a_char, 10);
                    myIntArray.add(temp);
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(myIntArray.get(rawSize)));
                    rawSize++;
                }
                charCounter++;
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
};
```

My output:

```
1 1
1 1
1 1
2 1
2 1
2 1
3 1
3 1
3 1
```

When i replace:`a_char = line.charAt(charCounter);` with `a_char = '5';`,
my output:

```
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
```

Can't understand why so.

Comment: More context please.

Comment: and post new questions. dont update the same question with different issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just rewritten your code to be able to compile it, and it works correctly:

```
String line = "2 2 2";
ArrayList myIntArray = new ArrayList();
int charCounter = 0;
int rawSize = 0;
while(charCounter < line.length()){
    char a_char = line.charAt(charCounter);
    if(a_char != ' '){
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(a_char)+" ");
        int temp = Character.digit(a_char, 10);
        myIntArray.add(temp);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(myIntArray.get(rawSize)));
        rawSize++;
    }
    charCounter++;
}
```

Output:

```
2 2
2 2
2 2
```

**Update:**
I have edited my code according your update. And again, it works correctly, but `String.valueOf(...)` indeed always return 1. This is because in the outer `while` you assign rawSize to zero, so you will always print the first three elements of `myIntArray`, which are '1's. Try to print the whole `myIntArray`, and you will see that it's filled as you expected.

P.S. There are really a lot of more concise and nice ways to accomplish this, as another responder suggests, for instance.

Comment: add my Main function. 
can't understand, where is bad conversion

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way by using `split()` method of a string to achieve what you want:

```
String[] lines = line.split(" ");
for(String s : lines)
   myIntArray.add(Integer.parseInt(s))
```